# How to set up my Kafka Connect in distributed mode for better perofmance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am running my Kafka connect for Elastic search in distributed mode .
Currently i have  2 EC2 instance (Instance type t2.2xlarge)

```
Number of vCPUs 8
Memory  32 Gb
```

I am running kafka connect on above instance type with max task as 2 .
I am planning to put heavy puts from producers which will put records into ElastciSearch using Kafka connect .

Heavy puts mean 10000 records per seconds .

Keeping this in mind how should i create Kafka connect .

For example

1. how many task should be required to handle this so that records can go Faster into ES?
2. Is 2 EC2 instance is enough for this load or do i need more ?
3. How many task is good to create for one EC2 instance ?
4. Having one bigger EC2 is better or having multiple EC2 with smaller instance is better ?
5. How i can confirm that all the records are de qued from Kafka topic to ES using Kafka connect ?

How shall i benchmark my Kafka connect performance ?

I am not using any schema registry as of now .

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have 2 EC2 instance

So you can only run 2 workers. Add more (in different AZs) for better fault tolerance. You need to add CPU and memory monitoring to know if you should add more instances.

> running kafka connect on above instance type with max task as 2 .

You can have up to as many tasks as input topic-partitions.

> 10000 records per seconds

Kafka can certainly handle that. You need to benchmark your ES indexers separately.

> How i can confirm that all the records are de qued from Kafka topic to ES using Kafka connect

You would monitor consumer group lag, same as any other consumer task

> Having one bigger EC2 is better or having multiple EC2 with smaller instance is better

"Better" is relative. If you want performance over cost, then pick larger instances and allocate more heap space.

Comment: Thank you ..lot to know now .How do we decide how much resource each task can take . I have a topic with 50 partition so i can create 50 tasks . Now how shall we decide how many task i should keep for each ec2 ? Is it like we have to run test and decide ? Any guidance at least to start with ?

Comment: I would just setup system /JMX monitoring. And observe resource utilization. You do not decide how many tasks go on each machine. The framework distributes tasks itself